# Where is TextTransform.exe located in mono for linux?

Tags: mono, t4

I am exploring a mono installation at work and is looking for TextTransform.exe. I've tried grepping for it but no success so far.

I wonder where TextTransform.exe normally is located? Is it an optional part of mono and therefore potentially not built?

We have version 1.2.6, 2.0.1 and 2.4.2 installed, I grepped through all versions looking for TextTransform.exe. I verified I can get T4 template to work in monodevelop (but I still like to to use TextTransform.exe).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

TextTransform.exe is part of MonoDevelop, not the actual mono runtime.

Comment: Is monodevelop part of mono runtime? Because that's installed in the mono folder at work.

Comment: MonoDevelop is not part of the mono runtime. TextTransform.exe is included with the text templating addin. It is in the AddIns\MonoDevelop.TextTemplating directory.

Comment: MonoDevelop licensing on that component however allows one to build and distribute TextTransform.exe (and it's requirements) freely. If you want to base a solution on T4 (as I've done), you can actually get around the limitations of Visual Studio SDK distribution rules. MonoDevelop's T4 is quite compatible with VS T4 (some include/path differences I recall).